# Excel VBA: Copy data from one workbook to another - PasteSpecial Error

Tags: excel, vba

I need help with a macro to copy one row of data into the next open space in a "master file" when desired.

The user clicks a button and fills out a form, then the data is copied, but I get an error, when I try to paste into the other workbook.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim emptyRow As Long
Dim Exists As Boolean
Dim answer As Integer
Dim toomany As Integer
Dim rm_master As Workbook
Dim rm_list As Worksheet
Dim vals As Variant

Sheet2.Range("A2").Value = IMCode.Value
Sheet2.Range("B2").Value = IMDescription.Value

Unload Me

Set rm_master = Workbooks.Open("C:\ExcelFiles\Master.xlsm")
Set rm_list = rm_master.Sheets("RMs")

emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("B143:B167"))
Exists = Sheet2.Range("P2").Value

If Exists = True Then
    answer = MsgBox("already exists.", vbOKOnly, "Already Exists")
Else
    If emptyRow + 143 > 167 Then
        toomany = MsgBox("Too many.  Please clean up or add rows.", vbOKOnly, "Too Many Codes")
    Else
        Sheet2.Range("A2:N2").Copy
        rm_master.rm_list.Cells(emptyRow + 143, 2).PasteSpecial
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

I get an error at the `.PasteSpecial` line. I have looked at other ways to use `.Value`s and other methods, but then I get an error on the copy step. My thought is because I am using `.Cells` to reference the start point for the `.Range` paste?

Comment: remove the `rm_master.` from that line.  The workbook is already part of the worksheet variable.

Comment: Seems way to easy but problem solved!  I guess i over defined it?

Comment: @RiverChawk take a look to your code, when you set your `rm_list` you are giving already the workbook, so there is no need to use `rm_master`. You'd use it when you have no variable for the worksheet: `rm_master.Sheets("MySheet").Cells(empyRow + 143, 2).PasteSpecial` for example.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now.  Kind of like calling it an ATM Machine (Automated Teller Machine Machine).